# jquery datepicker from to not working in popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pop window which contains jQuery from to datepicker. I'm not able to select the End date value.

jQuery call

```
$(function() {
  $("#createdFromDate").datepicker(
    {
      defaultDate : "+1w",
      changeMonth : true,
      numberOfMonths : 1,
      changeMonth : true,
      changeYear : true,
      onClose :
        function(selectedDate) {
          $("#createdToDate").datepicker(
            "option", "minDate", selectedDate
          );
        }
    }
  );
  $("#createdToDate").datepicker(
    {
      defaultDate : "+1w",
      changeMonth : true,
      numberOfMonths : 1,
      changeMonth : true,
      changeYear : true,
      onClose :
        function(selectedDate) {
          $("#createdFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate",selectedDate);
        }
    }
  );
});

$("#filterPopUp").dialog(
  {
    autoOpen : false,
    modal : true,
    height : 'auto',
    width : '70%'
  }
);

$(document).on('click', ".getTimeFeed",
  function() {
    $('#filterPopUp').dialog("open");
  }
);
```

This is my JSP page.

```
<div id="filterPopUp" class="filterPopUp" title="Custom Time">
  <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-6 col-xs-12" for="createdFromDate">
      Start Date: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-6 no-padding input-max controls">
      <input type="text" class="form-control  input-sm" name="createdFromDate"
             id="createdFromDate">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding"> 
    <label class="control-label col-sm-6 col-xs-12" for="createdToDate">
      End Date: </label> 
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-6 no-padding input-max controls">
      <input type="text" class="form-control  input-sm" name="createdToDate" id="createdToDate">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="actions" class="actions">
    <button type="button" id="feedFilterCancel" class="btn cancel-btn">
      <i class="icon-remove"></i>
      <fmt:message key="button.cancel" />
    </button>
    <button type="button" id="timeFilter" class="btn btn-primary">
      <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
      <fmt:message key="button.save" />
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the pop up window appears when i select the end date its not accepting it.

Comment: @user..please format your code..

Comment: Looks OK, is the jsp code and jquery in the same file?  Is the popup just a div that is visible?

Comment: Yes its in the same file and the pop up div is just that much!

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/P9pJG/2/

Comment: why you won't call the datepicker code like `$( ".selector" ).on( "dialogopen", function( event, ui ) { // call code here } );`

Comment: You should put the dialog initialization code inside the document ready function.

Comment: @Barmar I tried in JSFiddle. its working there. But in JSP popup window it is not working.

Comment: @Ravimallya how to use it? Can you show a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Structure:

```
$(function(){
    $("#createdToDate").datepicker();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this code: It is a plain HTML approach of your requirement.

```
$("#filterPopUp").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 'auto',
    width: '70%'
});
$("#filterPopUp").on("dialogopen", function (event, ui) {
    $("#createdFromDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#createdToDate").datepicker(
                "option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#createdToDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#createdFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

});
$(document).on('click', ".getTimeFeed",
  function() {
    $('#filterPopUp').dialog("open");
  }
);
```

It is working fine for me. You can check it at: http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/euwpD/1/